# How to solve double API fetch on universal ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

In current setup, I'm building multi-page universal web application (using react-router to do routing on both server and client). This project doesn't use any (redux) store (which I consider unneccessary for now).

One of component responsible for fetch data from remote API, done inside `componentWillMount` method.

When render on server, the component will fetch data, do rendering and send rendered HTML to client.

When client mount HTML with ReactJS, it fetch data once again from `componentWillMount` method. That's cause unneccessary double data fetch.

Does it have any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for answer from Dominic Tobias.

I tried develop a couple solution but I found one that suitable for me.

First, I decided not to fetch data either in `componentWillMount` or `componentDidMount` inside component, but create a static method call `fetchData` which return `Promise` like this:

```
class PageContainer extends Component {
    static fetchData(params) {
        return fetch('...URL...')
    }

    render() {
        const {data} = this.props;
        //render logic here
    }
}
```

and on server side, call `PageContainer.fetchData` and wait until promise is fulfilled, pass data as `props` to `PageContainer` and render HTML with hydrated data like this

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div id="roor">{..react rendered HTML..}</div>
        <script>window.__DATA__ = {..data..}</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

like I said, for this app, I think that redux is unnecessary for now.

Then, there is a problem on client side routing which is `react-router` cannot load async data. To fix that, I went looking for [AsyncProps](https://github.com/ryanflorence/async-props/blob/master/modules/AsyncProps.js) and write my own tiny version of that, called [AsyncComp](https://gist.github.com/tanapoln/f3439b13dada865e3944e81b56af5fc5). You can bootstrap React on client side with `react-router` like this:

```
const Root = <Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes} render={(props) => <AsyncComp {...props} data={window.__DATA__}/>}/>
ReactDOM.render(Root, document.getElementById("root"));
```

That's all.

PS. After I built `AsyncComp`, it can also be used on server side like this:

```
AsyncComp.fetchData(routerProps)
    .then((data) => {
      const html = ReactDOM.renderToString(<AsyncComp {...routerProps} data={data}/>)
      res.render('index', { html: html, data: data })
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your data already exists you should have a function which will make a conditional fetch which you can call on both the server and `componentDidMount` (you're not supposed to make ajax calls in `componentWillMount`).

For example this is how a component looks for me using redux:

```
class User extends Component {

  static readyOnActions(dispatch, params) {
    return Promise.all([
      dispatch(UserActions.fetchUserIfNeeded(params.id))
    ]);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    User.readyOnActions(this.props.dispatch, this.props.params);
  }
```

If this is the current page then the server will call the `readyOnActions`, and on the client `componentDidMount` can call the same thing - the action called `fetchUserIfNeeded` will only make an AJAX request if the server hasn't already done it by checking if the data already exists (and you can add further checks such as if it's valid, if it's not already fetching etc).